# C# com object result correctly processed?

Tags: c#, arrays, ole

*Sorry I don't know how to ask this question correctly.*

I'm a noob at C# and I'm trying to 'communicate' with an OLE server.
When I invoke the method, it sends a result but I don't know if I process it correctly.
The result is an error code from -1 to 13.

The result comes in 'convertImg' and if it's '-1' I want to change it to '14' so that I can use it in the array.

```
if (convertImg.Equals("-1")) {convertImg = 14;}
```

Is this correct?

Full code:

```
if (mediadentDic.Length > 0)
{
     List<string> mediadentMih = new List<string>();

     string[] mediadentError = {
         "No error", //0
         "Undefined",//1
         "ImageName not found", //2
         "There is no path info included in the source and/or destination filename", //3
         "MihImageName is not a .mih file", //4
         "Undefined", //5
         "Undefined", //6
         "Undefined", //7
         "Destination image already exists ", //8
         "Destination image file name is invalid ", //9
         "Invalid Export Type", //10
         "Invalid Quality value, must be 1..100", //11
         "Error occurred while loading the source image", //12
         "Error occurred while saving the destination image ", //13
         "Unspecified error", //-1 -> 14
     };
     foreach (string file in mediadentDic)
     {
         string mihPath = file.Substring(0, file.Length - 3) + "mih";
         mediadentMih.Add(mihPath);
     }
     foreach (string file in mediadentMih)
     {
         string mihImageName = file;
         string exportImageName = webDir + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".jpg";
         textBoxOutput.AppendText(Path.GetFileName(file) + " converteren..." + "\r\n");

         int exportImageType = 0;
         int exportImageQuality = 1;
         Object[] args = new Object[] { mihImageName, exportImageName, exportImageType, exportImageQuality, null };
         Object convertImg =  mediadentObject.GetType().InvokeMember("OleExportImage", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, mediadentObject, args);

         if (convertImg.Equals("-1"))
         {
             convertImg = 14;
         }

         if (convertImg.Equals(0))
         {
             textBoxOutput.AppendText("Converteren van " + Path.GetFileName(file) + " geslaagd" + "\r\n");
         }
         else
         {
              textBoxOutput.AppendText("Fout: " + convertImg + " " + mediadentError[Convert.ToInt32(convertImg)] + "\r\n");
         }
         i++;
         progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(i / total * 100, MidpointRounding.ToEven));
    }
}
```

Comment: If the result is an integer you are trying to compare it to an string, it will fail.

Comment: Ok, Can you explain how I should do it? Because I can't do this: if (convertImg == -1)
Edit: Without the quotes?

Comment: `if (convertImg.Equals(-1))`

Comment: @Gusman Ok thank you, that's a stupid mistake...
The problem is that I can't test it...